# Why are these lambdas considered different types?

Tags: c++, lambda, types, c++14

I found this odd behavior with `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, but the odd part has more to do with what I assume is correct behavior than a quirk in demangling. I could be wrong.

```
auto lambda1 = [] { return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; };
auto lambda2 = [] { return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; };
//static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(lambda1), decltype(lambda2)>(), "Distinct types!");
std::cout << pretty(lambda1) << "\n" << pretty(lambda2) << std::endl;
lambda1(); // ...with T = main(int, const char**)::<lambda()>
lambda2(); // ...with T = main(int, const char**)::<lambda()>
```

Now, it doesn't surprise me terribly that they aren't considered the same type - only that they're distinct and don't reflect it in their signature. (This works the same when the lambdas return null.) Why would that be?

I'll also point out that the return type isn't shown at all, which I've never seen omitted from a regular function. I'm certain the return type is both strongly typed and a fundamental part of the type of the lambda, so why would it be omitted?

Comment: `lambda`s aren't implemented as functions, they're implemented as functors; `class`es/`struct`s with `operator()` defined. Being methods on unrelated classes, they're not going to behave like normal functions.

Answer (score 5):

Each lambda *expression* denotes a *unique* closure type.

[`[expr.prim.lambda.closure]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-1)

> The type of a lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure
>   object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type, called the closure
>   type, whose properties are described below.

As to why `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` renders the same, you'd have to ask the implementer (it's not a standard macro), but at a guess it's hard to de-mangle to a name that is both unique and representative.

Comment: What about the return type of the lambda? That seems like par for the course, since it can do `&type::operator()` -> `std::string (type::*)(unsigned int)` and so on. It's fine if you don't know the details about `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, I knew it wasn't standard, I was mostly looking for details about lambda and why it *could* be different.

Comment: Oh, I guess it could capture and return itself, maybe it protects against self-referential types. A lambda wouldn't be able to declare itself with itself as an argument, so the parameters should be safe.